# How to select count different values by different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have issues to count data by different criteria and to display them on a chart. In the database, I have millions of entries when I try to count the total, the completed, the rejected and expired in daily, weekly and monthly bases, it doesn't show the correct answer. I have 189 on `2019-09-07` but on daily it shows `0` or the current date `2019-09-08` must be with `0` doesn't appear or a different value which doesn't match with the actual value selected directly by the workbench.

```
SELECT 
  D.dates AS dates, 
  IFNULL(V.total,0) AS total, 
  IFNULL(V.completed,0) AS complete, 
  IFNULL(V.rejected,0) AS rejected, 
  IFNULL(EX.e,0) AS expired 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY AS dates
    FROM (
      SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    ) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    ) AS b
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    ) AS c 
  ) AS generator 
  WHERE generator.dates BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
) AS D 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    DATE(live_date) AS live_date, 
    COUNT(*) as total, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'rejected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rejected
  FROM agreement 
  WHERE DATE(live_date) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
  GROUP BY DATE(live_date) 
  ORDER BY DATE(live_date) DESC
) AS V ON D.dates = V.live_date 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DATE(expire_date) AS dEx, COUNT(*) AS e 
  FROM agreement 
  WHERE status = 'open' 
  AND DATE(expire_date) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
  GROUP BY dEx 
  ORDER BY DATE(expire_date) DESC
) AS EX ON D.dates = EX.dEx;
```

Expecting to have the correct value for `total`, `completed`, `rejected` and `expired` in single `SELECT` to avoid high complexity and time to load the data instead of multiple `SELECT` with `JOIN`.

Comment: Please post sample data set along with expected output. Also, a fiddle link would be great to have.

Comment: @Samir Thanks for the prompt answer! Here is the fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/660a280/1), It works perfectly for a small number of entries but doesn't work when I have billions.

Comment: Counts and sums can go out of sync here because of nulls in the data- count(*) will count one for the presence of the row but your sums are only summing based on conditions for the data. I recommend you add the anti-condition as a count too (`sum case when status is null or status not in ('complete','rejected') then 1 else 0 end` to provide complete  counting coverage of the dataset so nothing "goes missing"

Comment: (And I would also recommend that you put your row generator into a view to reduce the visual complexity of your SQL a bit, and consider switching to the cross-database compatible COALESCE for changing nulls to 0, rather than MySQL specific IFNULL)

Comment: Thank you @CaiusJard, to mention that the status is not null, it is draft by default. The ```COUNT``` must count all rows, ```completed``` must count row which has ```status='complete'``` and ```rejected``` must count row which has ```status = 'completed'``` and the conditions which applies to all of them is that ```live_date``` must be between today and 90 days back.

Comment: The ```COALESCE()``` function returns the first non-null value from a row, it doesn't return the which I have four rows, I don't think if it is ideal.

Comment: The COALESCE function returns the first non null argument from left to right. `COALESCE(v.total, 0)` returns v.total if it is not null or 0 if it is. It is exactly the same as your use of `IFNULL(v.total,0)` except a) it works in all database products and hence makes a worthy upgrade to your sql knowledge / resumee and b) it accepts more than two arguments so is occasionally more useful

Comment: I make the suggestion that you should cover the cases where your conditional sums don't work out so that you can know where things have gone wrong. You're here complaining that your counts are "total=189, complete=0, rejected=0, expired=0" and wonder why 0+0+0 doesn't add up to 189; it's because there are other statuses and row values that are falling outside of what you count. I'm saying if you work up something to show them then you can see where they have gone, and you can chase down the bug

Comment: Thank you @CaiusJard! I was counting the total, completed and rejected based on live date which is not correct the completed and rejected must be counted based on finalized date, as they are ```0000-00-00 00:00:00``` and after the status changes it will receive a value of current date and time. I created now a new ```SELECT``` and added a new ```LEFT JOIN``` only for these two and it is working. But I am still thinking how I can have all total, completed, rejected and expired counted in just one select base on ```live_date, finalized_date, and expire_date```?

Comment: I was also thinking to make a comment on the difficulties of using multiple different dates. If you have things that may complete on jan1 but expire on jan3 it's hard to assert they should be in the same total if the totals are done by day; the set of applications that expire on jan3 are not the same applications that are complete on jan 3 but explaining this to users will turn a blank face. Have a careful think about how to connect your data, or don't provide a total, or provide a total that isn't independent of the other variables but just a sum of them